# What is the origin/meaning of wish't?

Tags: meaning

I've stumbled upon an old documentary where an Irish bible salesman sings "wish't I was a rich man" (written as such in the subtitles)

I've seen it in some other songs... but it seems very rare.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Could it just be Irish accent?

Comment: A deletion from "I wish that I was a rich man." Obviously also an indicative-where-many-champion-the-irrealis-were.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like a dialectal spelling of "wish(ed?)". I found it in the songs/poems "Wish't I wuz a gurl" and (close enough) "Wush't I wuz a boy" (example in [Health](https://books.google.com/books?id=vWkhAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22wish%27t%20i%20%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBtNSzxJX1AhVKknIEHRoxBGgQuwV6BAgDEAY)). Here's an earlier example from [1822](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Blackwood_s_Edinburgh_Magazine/fIlIAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22wish%27t+i+%22&pg=PA499&printsec=frontcover): "I wish't, I want it".

I found "wysht" in the [MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED52961/track) as a spelling for the past tense, which might be related or not. (That's really not different from "spelt".)